# When function completed call ajax update

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following javascript and ajax function in the same page - I want the ajax dis() function to be activated when the first function has been activated and completed

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function addStock(event) {
        var element = event.target;
        var symbol = element.getAttribute("symbol");

        if (confirm("Add Symbol to Watchlist " + symbol + "?")) {
            $.post("watchlistinsert.php?symbol="+ symbol");
            console.log("item " + symbol + " added");

           //Here i want to call the function dis()

        } else {

            console.log("user canceled");
        }
        return;
    }


</script>
```

```
function dis()
{

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "select.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}

dis();

setInterval(function(){
    dis();
},10000);
```

Comment: You should use promises.

Comment: `$.post("watchlistinsert.php?symbol="+ symbol",  dis);`

Comment: Have you considered reading [the documentation of `$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)?

Comment: @keith, OMG, that works, so simple and straightforward. My IDE first suggested, dis() - which did not work - just dis after the link works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FelixKling - yes i have read this and tried to add the function as on success - without success :/

Comment: In general you should show us what you have tried. Passing `dis()` cannot work. You have to pass a **function** to `$.post`. `dis()` would pass the **return value** of `dis` to `$.post`. But `dis` doesn't return a function...

Comment: @FelixKling - the simple answer from Keith worked.   $.post("watchlistremove.php?symbol="+ symbol, dis);

Comment: I know. I only explained why.